# How to align two inner divs inside outer absolute positioned div that has fixed width in which both divs have the same width?

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that has absolute position with fixed width 559px. I want to have div1 and div2 have the same width and make sure the contents of each div does not go outside the fixed width.

Here is what i have now :

```
    <div id="top">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </div>


#top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:559px;
    height:133px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#div1
{


}
#div2
{


}
```

I am missing the style for div1 and div2. How can I achieve that ?.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply float the two divs and give them half of the width:

```
#div1, #div2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkxWP/1/

Comment: Works without the `position:relative`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give any styling to #div1-2... Just add

```
#div1, #div2
{
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W5fSx/2/)**

CSS

```
    #top{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:559px;
    height:133px;
    background-color:black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#div1, #div2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color:white;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#div1
{
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;

}
#div2
{
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEKm5/)